# Death Itself - A Linguistic Puzzle

Tags: riddle

I am death itself, yet I was forged by a life.

From what I am structured upon is golden.

I have been written and rewritten time and time again

I, myself, have been taken from and rearranged, yet I remain generic.

You see me most anywhere there is space to be filled, words to be written.

And yet, no one quite knows why.

My language has formed many a way of speech.

***What am I?***

Comment: please do select the correct answer else answer it yourself.

Comment: @AditKirtani It's been barely a few weeks. The correct answer need not be given just because you're not patient enough.

Comment: @Nij ok ok sorry.

Comment: @Nij do you think it has been long enough?

Answer (score 6):

You are:

> History

Explanation:

I am death itself, yet I was forged by a life.

> Many people trying get their names in history have died. People who are living frame records of the past.

From what I am structured upon is golden.

> History can showcase the Golden Ages of many rulers.

I have been written and rewritten time and time again

> In many cases, history can be very contradicting.

I, myself, have been taken from and rearranged, yet I remain generic.

> Sometimes with the contradictory statements, people put certain events in different times, *rearranging* history. Yet history still remains generic as it always will point down to that one event from which multiple speculations have come up.

You see me most anywhere there is space to be filled, words to be written.

> When we wonder about something (space) history helps us fill that void with knowledge of the past.

And yet, no one quite knows why.

> No one knows why some events turn out or happen. For example: [Mary Celeste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Celeste)

My language has formed many a way of speech.

> All modern languages are derived from a few ancient languages.

Answer (score 4):

You might be

> rest

I am death itself, yet I was forged by a life.

> Resting can mean dead, but beings rest too.

From what I am structured upon is golden.

> A rest can be a silence, and silence is golden.

I have been written and rewritten time and time again

> This could hint to the many rests in music notation.

I, myself, have been taken from and rearranged, yet I remain generic.

> Arrangement could also hint at music, and it is not that specific.

You see me most anywhere there is space to be filled, words to be written.

> A rest, a pause, a space, could fit in between words.

And yet, no one quite knows why.

> No idea here

My language has formed many a way of speech.

> Rest being somewhat related to silence, this might relate to sign languages?

Comment: I agree why there is line "And yet, no one quite knows why." it doesn't make any of the sense

Answer (score 0):

One is guess is:

> You are a Question.

I am death itself, yet I was forged by a life.

> Question of life and death

From what I am structured upon is golden.

> Questions seek the golden truth. Questions are built based on a set of grammatical rules (golden standards).

I have been written and rewritten time and time again

> It's always a question of time.

I, myself, have been taken from and rearranged, yet I remain generic.

> We use and reuse many generic questions.

You see me most anywhere there is space to be filled, words to be written.

> We can and tend to question anything, both physically and metaphysically

And yet, no one quite knows why.

> Why? is the biggest question.

My language has formed many a way of speech.

> Some people always finish their sentences with questions. We often use rhetorical questions as a way of making statements.

Comment: hmm I don't know seems okay haha

Comment: Are you saying it's the answer, but I didn't get all the references right?

Comment: The line ***I have been written and rewritten time and time again*** is not what I agree on mostly but haha idk

Comment: But I am on the right track overall?

Comment: Does it "matter"? ;)

Comment: But your answer is the only one which explains ***And yet, no one quite knows why.***

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40451/discussion-between-rahul-srinath-and-hypejunction).